# SQL Server Database Document Generator in .CHM format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, documentation, database-administration

I want to generate the DB document for all DB objects. please provide the free open source software to create the DB document.

I have used the SQLDBdoc but it's provide the only Tables details.

I am using SQl server 2012 express editions.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server documentation tools are quite complex to be free and open source and often they lack features. Instead, I suggest trying out some of the commercial tools with free versions, that are available on the market.

For example,  I’m using [ApexSQL Doc](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx) as a documentation tool. The program generates full featured SQL Server database and BI documentations in 5 output formats (including chm) in a few clicks, and lets you pick the database objects to document. It also offers different output style templates for the documentation.

It comes with a 14 days trial period and after that it remains free as a Community edition and lets you document from SQL Server Express and Azure SQL Database in chm format.